# Get data from Soap Xml API using CURL or SOAP Object

Tags: magento2, xml, soap, curl

I want to integrate some out soap API data with magento store and want to get data from [soap API](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/webapi/get-started/soap-web-api-calls/).

For this I have two methods to get data one is using `curl` and other is using `soapClient object`, and from both methods I am getting same data but I want to know what is the best method to get data from soap API.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest to use soapClient object.

Answer (score 0):

The preferred method of accessing the SOAP API is via `soapClient`. That is exactly what the PHP class is for.